# Preprocessor and double declaration include in different files

Tags: c++, compilation

I am wondering how compiler (or preprocessor) include headers. I have three files. First is header.h, second first.cpp <- and there is `#include <iostream>`, third <- it contains `#include <iostream>` too.

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

struct Student
{
    std::string imie;
    int ocena;
};


void foo();

#endif
```

first.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    Student Jan;
    std::cout << "It's OK" << std::endl;
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Second.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "I like Linux" << std::endl;
}
```

And my question is do the compiler copy code from library twice? Should I cut all `iostream` from .cpp's to one .h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the source code of the `iostream` header, you will see it includes header guard as well, meaning the header will be included only once.

For example the GCC guards the header with the `_GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM` constant.

Comment: Thank you for help, but where can I find all libraries (in Linux (this is more important for me) and Windwos)?

Comment: @diego9403 You could always just google `* source code`, such as `iostream source code`. With closed-source libraries you are obviously going to have less luck and need to trust the creator of the library it was written well.